# k6 Load Testing: Pause a ramping-vus test execution then resume it by terminal command

Tags: javascript, performance-testing, load-testing, pause, k6

As I was checking, k6 provides load testers to pause/resume a live running test (as per docu: https://k6.io/blog/how-to-control-a-live-k6-test/)

Please see my set up.

```
export const options = {

ext: {
    loadimpact: {
        projectID: 1234,
        // Test runs with the same name groups test runs together
        name: "test",

        distribution: {
            "amazon:sg:singapore": {
                loadZone: "amazon:sg:singapore",
                percent: 100,
            },
        },

    }
},

stages: [
    { duration: "1m", target: 150 },
    { duration: "3m", target: 150 },
    { duration: "1m", target: 0 },
],

 };


  export default function() {
let response;
const vars = {};

response = http.get(https://test.com);
sleep(5);
 }
```

Please note also that I am running the output on the k6 cloud.

After running the test…I tried making use of the k6 pause command. I opened a new terminal and entered the command : ***k6 pause*** …but it displayed an error.

***ERRO[0000] Pause error: ramping-vus executor ‘default’ doesn’t support pause and resume operations after its start***

Is there a way for me to work this out? I need to manually pause the live test and resume it whenever I want to.

OR is there a way from k6 wherein we can add a line in the script that will automatically pause the execution after a condition is met. For example. Pause the execution after all VUs were able to iterate one time. Then I can resume the test manually whenever I want to by inputting a command (for example: ***k6 resume***).

Any help or discussion is much appreciated. Thanks.